# Replace string with multiline file content

Tags: command-line, bash, sed, perl, text-processing

I need to replace string `SALT` in a file with content of another file. Problem is that the input file has multilines. I tried something like this in my bash script:

```
SALT=`cat salt.txt`;
sed "s/SALT/$SALT/" wp-config.php > result.txt
```

It work's fine when the *salt.txt* is single line, but if there are more lines it fails. I've read that it could do PERL. But I don't know how. Could you help me?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Another `perl` way:

```
perl -pe 's/SALT/`cat salt.txt`/e' wp-config.php > result.txt
```

The key here is the `/e` regexp option allowing us to use a `perl` command result as a substitution string.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to stick to `bash`, choose a character that doesn't appear in neither your string nor in your file, let's say `@`; then:

```bsh
SALT=`< salt.txt tr '\n' '@'`
sed "s/SALT/$SALT/" wp-config.php | tr '@' '\n' > result.txt
```

This way before the replacement the `newline` characters in your string are changed to `@` and after the replacement the `@` characters are changed back to `newlines`, so that `SALT` is not treated as an array anymore but just as a variable containing a long string.

Answer (score 1):

You can do this:

```
sed -e "/SALT/{r salt.txt" -e "d}" wp-config.php  > result.txt
```

Where `salt.txt` is the salt, `wp-config.php` is the input file and `SALT` is the string to replace

Comment: This will replace whole line with content of file *salt.txt* if containing a SALT in it not *SALT* word itself!!

Comment: is there anyway to fix this? instead of replacing the whole line, just the keyword

Answer (score 0):

```
perl -e 'open my $S, "<", "salt.txt" or die $!;
         $salt = do { local $/ ; <$S> };
         s/SALT/$salt/, print while <>;
        ' wp-config.php > result.txt
```

The first line opens the `salt.txt`.

The second line reads it contents into the $salt variable.

The third takes the command line arguments as file names, reads the files line by line and replaces the string.